# Visual Interface to a Mac server

Tags: server, ssh, connection

I am trying to connect to a mac server so that I have a visual interface as if it was a virtual desktop... I think. I have the server information and access i.e I can ssh onto the server. Any ideas on how I would do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't do this with ssh cause ssh is just another Protocol to just do remote Login on a System over a Terminal/Console just like telnet.

What you're looking for is VNC.

2 Things needed 1st the VNC Server Service/Function must be activated/running on the Mac Server and 2nd You need a VNC Client on your local PC.